# Shell: Output text to PNG while preserving color

Tags: shell, colors, images, imagemagick

I like to be able to save the output of a shell command as a PNG image without losing the formatting. Kind of like taking a screenshot of the output.

```
some-command-with-color | text-to-png a.png
```

I know this command converts text to PNG, but it doesn’t preserve color:

```
tldr -c tldr | convert -page  4000x4000 -font FreeMono -pointsize 20  -background white -trim +repage -bordercolor white  -border 15 text:- png:a.png
```

[image]

Comment: @terdon Not really, there is no running terminal emulator to take a screenshot of. I want a script to convert ansi output to png.

Answer (score 10):

A program that does that is [`ansilove`](https://github.com/ansilove/ansilove). It is already packaged for many distributions.

For example:

```
$ ls --color > /tmp/output.ansi
$ ansilove -o /tmp/output.png /tmp/output.ansi
```

Comment: Sadly, I get incorrect colors with this

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [ansilove](https://github.com/ansilove/ansilove), there are also [ansigo](https://github.com/ansilove/ansigo) (made by the same persons but much simpler) and [AnsiToImg](https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/AnsiToImg) or [textimg](https://github.com/jiro4989/textimg).

### AnsiToImg

```bash
# installation
pip install ansitoimg

# from file to image
ansitoimg /tmp/dcd.log dcd.svg

# pipeline
ls --color=always /etc | ansitoimg ls.svg

# preserving color in pipeline
unbuffer grc ss -nlpt | ansitoimg ss.svg

# use theme and wide screen
dcd -d za.tryhackme.com -s 10.200.28.101 | ansitoimg -w -t /tmp/one-dark.yaml /tmp/dcd.png
```

### textimg

```bash
# from file to image
cat /tmp/dcd.log| textimg -o out.png

# pipeline
ls --color=always /etc | textimg -o out.png

# preserving color in pipeline
unbuffer grc ss -nlpt | textimg -o out.png

# choose font (-f), emoji font (-e) and use emoji font (-i)
dcd -d za.tryhackme.com -s 10.200.28.101 | textimg -f /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Anonymous\ Pro.ttf -e /usr/share/fonts/joypixels/JoyPixels.ttf -i -o /tmp/out.png
```